# Presenting viewcontroller over current context is modal and does not rotate correctly

Tags: ios, swift, overlay, viewcontroller, popover

This is with iOS 11.4, Swift 4 and Xcode 9.

Im trying to present a viewcontroller over current context, so that the underlying context gets dimmed but still visible. I do this with following code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)l
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginView") as! LoginViewController
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
vc.modalTransitionStyle   = .coverVertical

present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
let ppc = vc.popoverPresentationController
                
ppc?.sourceView = tableView
ppc?.sourceRect = tableView.bounds
ppc?.delegate = vc
```

LoginViewController has a view (popview) centered in it's mainview which contains my editable controls.
This works initially fine but I got a few problems:

1. The presented viewcontroller behaves modal. I.e. I cannot dismiss it by clicking outside popview. This is, as I assume, because the presenting viewcontrollers view never receives the touch events because they are captutered by the presented view.
2. Upon device rotation to landscape only part of the screen is filled with the dimmed view of LoginViewController.

I tried to fix problem 1 by using a passtrough view for the LoginViewController's main view with

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
{
    let view = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    return view == self ? nil : view
}
```

This doesn't help.
I could use a UITapGestureRecognizer on the mainview and call dismiss from there if the touch is not withing popview, but that seems to be rather clumsy to me and I wonder if there is a better way.

I have no idea how to solve problem 2. I tried the delegate functions of the UIPopoverPresentationController but this doesn't work either because
vc.popoverPresentationController is always nil when I use .overCurrentContext.

When I set modalPresentationStyle to .popover I get a value for the popoverPresentationController, but than my LoginView will cover the presenting controllers view completely.

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging around I found eventually a solution for problem 2 doing it the Android way:

In the **presenting** view controller I added to functions:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?)
{
    if (loginViewController != nil)
    {
        present(loginViewController!, animated:false, completion: nil)
    }
}
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    loginViewController!.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

Thus when a orientation change is incoming the popover view is first dismissed and after the change has been performed the popover is presented again. As the presented viewcontroller is unharmed during this process even data already entered in the presented viewcontroller's controls remain.

To solve problem 1 I added in the **presented** viewcontroller:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{ 
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

and

```
@objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let touchpoint = sender.location(in: view)
    let popviewrect = popview.frame

    if (!popviewrect.contains(touchpoint))
    {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        delegate?.onDismissed()
    }      
}
```

The **presenting** controller implements the *onDismissed* delegate:

```
func onDismissed()
{
    loginViewController = nil
}
```

Still wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this